Spinoza's Ethics. He didn't explain why substance has infinite attributes
My point of reference is up to Proposition 11:
God is defined as a substance of infinite attributes, yet in Ethics, Spinoza didn't prove that substance necessarily has infinite substances. He proved substance is infinite because there can't be two substances of the same attribute, thus a substance of a given attribute is infinite, but it doesn't contradict its being with finite attributes, with each being infinite (Making substance infinite in such a way).
I could argue that there could be two substances or more, each with entirely different attributes, one limiting the other, yet each substance is infinite since their infinite by attribute.

Ax.6 God is absolutely infinite and see note.

What you're referring to is definition 6 and not axiom 6. However, even if God is defined in such a way, it doesn't mean that it exists (at least not by having infinite attributes). Much like how we have a definition for unicorn, yet it doesn't exist.
In the note, it says what he means by absolute infinity which is different than infinite by kind, however in proposition 8, the proof for substance's infinity was made by ruling out the substance as being finite by kind, and not absolutely.
